# Does the feat Mobile Spellcasting allow movement when casting during a grapple?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, actions, grapple, spellcasting

If a character is engaged in a grapple and has the feat *Mobile Spellcasting* (*Complete Adventurer*, p.111), are they allowed to make a grapple check to perform the [*Move* action](http://dndsrd.net/specialAttacks.html#grapple-move) alongside their spellcasting?

*Mobile Spellcasting* reads, in-part:

> You can make a special Concentration check (DC 20 + spell level) when casting a spell. If the check succeeds, you can cast the spell and move up to your speed as a single standard action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Not without an extra action.

The Move grapple action requires a standard action. Mobile Spellcasting allows you to cast a spell and move up to your speed as a standard action; it does not allow you to cast a spell and perform some other standard action which also happens to involve movement. So to use both the Move grapple action and Mobile Spellcasting in one turn requires two standard actions.